# image not displaying on safari

Tags: php, image, browser, safari

I'm trying to take an image from user and display it. but somehow its not showing on browser. I'm using safari at the moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Uploading a Photo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST["sendPhoto"] ) ) 
{
    processForm();

} 
else 
{
    displayForm();
}

function processForm() {
    if ( isset( $_FILES["photo"] ) and $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
        if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] != "image/jpeg" ) 
        {
            echo "<p>JPG photos only, thanks!</p>";
        } 
        elseif ( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"/Library/WebServer/Documents/image/".basename( $_FILES["photo"]["name"]))) 
        {
            echo "<p>Sorry, there was a problem uploading that photo.</p>".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];   
        } 
        else 
        {
            displayThanks();
        }
    } else {
        switch( $_FILES["photo"]["error"]) 
        {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            $message = "The photo is larger than the server allows.";
            break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            $message = "The photo is larger than the script allows.";
            break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $message = "No file was uploaded. Make sure you choose a file to upload.";
            break;
            default:
            $message = "Please contact your server administrator for help.";
        }
        echo "<p>Sorry, there was a problem uploading that photo. $message</p>";
    }}

    function displayForm() {
        ?>
        <h1>Uploading a Photo</h1>
        <p>Please enter your name and choose a photo to upload, then click Send Photo.    </p>
        <form action="photo_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div style="width: 30em;">
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />
                <label for="visitorName">Your name</label>
                <input type="text" name="visitorName" id="visitorName" value="" />
                <label for="photo">Your photo</label>
                <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="" />
                <div style="clear: both;">
                    <input type="submit" name="sendPhoto" value="Send Photo" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    function displayThanks() {
        ?>
        <h1>Thank You</h1>
        <p>Thanks for uploading your photo<?php if ( $_POST["visitorName"] )echo ", " . $_POST["visitorName"] ?>!</p>
        <p>Here's your photo:</p>
        <p><img src="/Library/WebServer/Documents/image/<?php echo $_FILES['photo']['name'] ?>" alt="Photo" width="20em" height="30em"/></p>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine but when I run on browser it save the input image to the directory but don't show it on page. instate of that it shows a '?' mark .

I tried everything but can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `/Library/WebServer/Documents` from the image source attribute.